# How to make an enum conform to a protocol in Swift?

Tags: swift, enums, swift-protocols

Swift documentation says that *classes*, *structs*, and *enums* can all conform to protocols, and I can get to a point where they all conform. But I can't get the *enum* to behave quite like the *class* and *struct* examples:

```
protocol ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String { get set }
    mutating func adjust()
}

class SimpleClass: ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String = "A very simple class."
    var anotherProperty: Int = 69105

    func adjust() {
        simpleDescription += " Now 100% adjusted."
    }
}

var a = SimpleClass()
a.adjust()
let aDescription = a.simpleDescription

struct SimpleStructure: ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String = "A simple structure"

    mutating func adjust() {
        simpleDescription += " (adjusted)"
    }
}

var b = SimpleStructure()
b.adjust()
let bDescription = b.simpleDescription

enum SimpleEnum: ExampleProtocol {
    case Base

    var simpleDescription: String {
        get {
            return "A Simple Enum"
        }
        set {
            newValue
        }
    }

    mutating func adjust() {
        self.simpleDescription += ", adjusted"
    }
}

var c = SimpleEnum.Base
c.adjust()
let cDescription = c.simpleDescription
```

I haven't figured out how to get the `simpleDescription` to change as a result of calling `adjust()`.  My example obviously won't do that because the *getter* has a value hard-coded, but how can I set a value for the `simpleDescription` while still conforming to the `ExampleProtocol`?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

This is my attempt:

```
protocol ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String { get }
    mutating func adjust()
}

enum ExampleEnum : ExampleProtocol {
    case Base, Adjusted

    var simpleDescription: String {
        return self.getDescription()
    }

    func getDescription() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .Base:
            return "A simple description of enum"
        case .Adjusted:
            return "Adjusted description of enum"
        }
    }

    mutating func adjust() {
        self = ExampleEnum.Adjusted
    }
}

var c = ExampleEnum.Base
c.adjust()
let cDescription = c.simpleDescription
```

Comment: Awesome!  I had that idea of creating an adjusted state, but it didn't occur to me that I could change to .Adjusted in the adjust method.  Thanks!

Comment: Excellent pointer.  Was a bit stuck on this one.

One question though: Any reason you added the return value of Void to the adjust function?

Comment: @jpittman because the `adjust` function returns `Void` in the `ExampleProtocol`, it's the same as just using `mutating func adjust()`. If you want `adjust` to have a return type, you can change the protocol to: https://gist.github.com/anjerodesu/e1bf640576a3b6fa415f

Comment: Could not edit the answer to correct the syntax error, it is missing a dot, should be `case .Base:`

Comment: can someone 69 this post. also #POP is touchy subject. visa once tested me heavy #POP interview question.

Answer (score 47):

Here is my take at it.

As this is an `enum` and not a `class`, you have to *think different(TM)*: it is your description that has to change when the "state" of your `enum` changes (as pointed out by @hu-qiang).

```
enum SimpleEnumeration: ExampleProtocol {
  case Basic, Adjusted

  var description: String {
    switch self {
    case .Basic:
      return "A simple Enumeration"
    case .Adjusted:
      return "A simple Enumeration [adjusted]"
    }
  }

  mutating func adjust()  {
    self = .Adjusted
  }
}

var c = SimpleEnumeration.Basic
c.description
c.adjust()
c.description
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i agree with your take on the enum itself, and with the code you provided. nice.

Comment: This answer is nicer and more succinct than the accepted one.

Comment: Just a side note that you can remove the SimpleEnumeration.Adjusted and replace with just ".Adjusted".  If the name of the enumeration ever changes then it's one less thing to refactor.

Comment: Yeah, this is better. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't conform to the given protocol though

Answer (score 12):

Here's another approach, using only the knowledge gained from the tour until that point*

```
enum SimpleEnumeration: String, ExampleProtocol {
    case Basic = "A simple enumeration", Adjusted = "A simple enumeration (adjusted)"

    var simpleDescription: String {
        get {
            return self.toRaw()
        }
    }

    mutating func adjust() {
        self = .Adjusted
    }
}

var c = SimpleEnumeration.Basic
c.adjust()
let cDescription = c.simpleDescription
```

If you want to have `adjust()` act as a toggle (although there's nothing to suggest this is the case), use:

```
mutating func adjust() {
    switch self {
    case .Basic:
        self = .Adjusted
    default:
        self = .Basic
    }
}
```

*(Although it doesn't explicitly mention how to specify a return type *and* a protocol)

Comment: I think this approach is probably the best one of the bunch. Quick update is that the simpleDescription should return self.rawValue

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution that doesn't change the current enum value, but their instance values instead (just in case it is useful to anyone).

```
enum ProtoEnumeration : ExampleProtocol {
    case One(String)
    case Two(String)

    var simpleDescription: String {
        get {
            switch self {
            case let .One(desc):
                return desc
            case let .Two(desc):
                return desc
            }
        }
    }
    mutating func adjust() {
        switch self {
        case let .One(desc):
            self = .One(desc + ", adjusted 1")
        case let .Two(desc):
            self = .Two(desc + ", adjusted 2")
        }
    }
}

var p = ProtoEnumeration.One("test")
p.simpleDescription
p.adjust()
p.simpleDescription
```

Comment: Extra points for whoever finds a way to avoid all those switches. Something along the lines of this fictitious copy `self = copy(self, self.desc + ", asdfasdf")`

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to define variables without getter and setter in enums and therefore it is impossible to have a variable that you can modify.

You can conform to the protocol but you cannot have same behavior with mutating as in classes.

Answer (score 2):

It is a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_185) about enum in swift.

Structures and enumerations are value types. By default, the properties of a value type cannot be modified from within its instance methods. [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_185)

Then, you have to use mutating function.

```
enum ProtocolEnum: ExampleProtocol {
    case on, off
    var simpleDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .on:
            return "Switch is ON"
        case .off:
            return "Switch is OFF"
        }
    }
    mutating func adjust() {
        switch self {
        case .on:
            self = off
        case .off:
            self = on
        }
    }
}

var c = ProtocolEnum.on
c.simpleDescription
c.adjust()
let cDescription = c.simpleDescription
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is for adjust() to flip between cases as follows:

```
enum SimpleEnum: ExampleProtocol {
    case Foo, Bar

    var simpleDescription: String {
    get {
        let value = self == .Foo
            ? "Foo"
            : "Bar"
        return "A simple \(value) enum."
    }
    }

    mutating func adjust() {
        self = self == .Foo
            ? .Bar
            : .Foo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's building on Jack's answer:

```
protocol ICanWalk {
    var description: String { get }
    mutating func stepIt()
}

enum TwoStepsForwardThreeStepsBack: Int, ICanWalk {
    case Base = 0, Step1, Step2

    var description: String {
        return "Step \(self.rawValue)"
    }

    mutating func stepIt() {
        if let nextStep = TwoStepsForwardThreeStepsBack( rawValue: self.rawValue + 1 ) {
            // going forward.
            self = nextStep
        } else {
            // back to the base.
            self = TwoStepsForwardThreeStepsBack.Base
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this

```
protocol ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String { get }
    mutating func adjust()
}

enum Seat: ExampleProtocol {
    case WindowSeat, MiddleSeat, AisleSeat

    var simpleDescription : String {
        switch self {
        case .WindowSeat:
            return "Window Seat"
        case .MiddleSeat:
            return "Middle Seat"
        case .AisleSeat:
            return "Aisle Seat"
        }
    }

    mutating func adjust() {
        switch self {
        case .WindowSeat:
            self = .MiddleSeat
        case .MiddleSeat:
            self = . AisleSeat
        case .AisleSeat:
            self = .WindowSeat
        }
    }
}

var seat = Seat.MiddleSeat
print(seat.simpleDescription) // Middle Seat
seat.adjust()
print(seat.simpleDescription) // Aisle Seat
```

Answer (score 1):

**Another variation: Using associated values to hold and display previous option**
(of the form "Selected 1, adjusted from 2, adjusted from 1, adjusted from 2, adjusted from 1")

```
protocol ExampleProtocol {
     var simpleDescription: String { get }
     mutating func adjust()
}

indirect enum EnumWithDescription: ExampleProtocol {
    case option1(EnumWithDescription?)
    case option2(EnumWithDescription?)
    var simpleDescription: String {
        return "Selected " + getDescription()
    }
    internal func getDescription() -> String {
        var currentValue: String
        let previousValue : EnumWithDescription?
        switch self {
        case .option1(let previous):
            currentValue = "1"
            previousValue = previous
        case .option2(let previous):
            currentValue = "2"
            previousValue = previous
        }
        if let adjustedFrom = previousValue?.getDescription() {
            return "\(currentValue) adjusted from \(adjustedFrom)"
        }
        else {
            return "\(currentValue)"
        }
    }
    mutating func adjust() {
        switch self {
        case .option1:
            self = .option2(self)
        case .option2:
            self = .option1(self)
        }
    }
}
var d = EnumWithDescription.option1(nil)
d.simpleDescription
d.adjust()
d.adjust()
d.simpleDescription
// Output: "Selected 1, adjusted from 2, adjusted from 1, adjusted from 2, adjusted from 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

here's my code

```
enum SimpleEnum: ExampleProtocol {
    case Base, Adjusted
    var simpleDescription: String {
        get {
            var description = "A simple enum."
            switch self {
            case .Base:
                return description
            case .Adjusted:
                return description + " - [adjusted]"
            }
        }
    }
    mutating func adjust() {
        self = SimpleEnum.Adjusted
    }
}
var simpleEnum = SimpleEnum.Base
simpleEnum.adjust()
simpleEnum.simpleDescription
```

Answer (score 0):

My first contribution here:

```
enum SimpleEnum: ExampleProtocol {
    case Basic(String), Adjusted(String)
    init() {
        self = SimpleEnum.Basic("A simple Enum")

    }

    var simpleDescription: String {
        get {
            switch self {
            case let .Basic(string):
                return string
            case let .Adjusted(string):
                return string
            }
        }
    }

    mutating func adjust() {
        self = SimpleEnum.Adjusted("full adjusted")

    }
}

var c = SimpleEnum()
c.adjust()
let cDescription = c.simpleDescription
```

Thanks for others!

Comment: Could you also add an explanation?

Comment: @Robert it should be self explained like others but the different are that I am using init method in enum and have default basic enum. so you'll see that when you create enum object like in structure and class example in Swift playground.

Answer (score 0):

This experiment threw me off too, due to the previous SimpleClass and SimpleStructure examples showing the property simpleDescription being modified internally, which caused me to think that I needed to do the same thing. After looking over the other answers posted here and reading the official Apple Swift 2.1 documentation, I came up with this:

```
protocol ExampleProtocol {
     var simpleDescription: String { get }
     mutating func adjust()
}

enum SimpleEnum: ExampleProtocol {
    case Simple
    case Adjusted

    var simpleDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .Simple:
            return "A simple enumeration"
        case .Adjusted:
            return "A simple enumeration somewhat changed."
        }
    }

    mutating func adjust() {
        self = .Adjusted
    }

    mutating func restore() {
        self = .Simple
    }
}

var d: SimpleEnum = .Simple
d.simpleDescription

d.adjust()
d.simpleDescription

d.restore()
d.simpleDescription
```

Also notice that in the examples given by Apple for SimpleClass and SimpleStructure prior to this experiment, the simple description is lost internally - you cannot get the original value back (unless of course you save it outside of the class/structure); this is what prompted me to create a restore() method for the SimpleEnum example, which allows you to toggle it back and forth between values. Hope this is useful to someone!

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking that the goal is simply to retain state and use a description to make the current state easier to read:

```
enum SimpleEnum: ExampleProtocol {

    case Default, Adjusted

    init() {
        self = .Default
    }

    var simpleDescription: String { get { return "\(self) Value" }}

    mutating func adjust() {
        self = .Adjusted
    }
}

var simpleEnum = SimpleEnum()
simpleEnum.adjust()
let adjustedSimple = simpleEnum.simpleDescript
```

Answer (score -1):

how about this

```
enum SimpleEnum : ExampleProtocol {
    case Desc(String)
    init() {
        self = Desc("a simple enum")
    }
    var simpleDescription:String {
        get {
            return (Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first!.value as? String)!
        }
    }
    mutating func adjust() {
        self = SimpleEnum.Desc(self.desc + " adjusted")
    }
}
var e = SimpleEnum()
e.simpleDescription    # => "a simple enum"
e.adjust()
e.simpleDescription    # => "a simple enum adjusted"
```