# How to conform an enumeration to Identifiable protocol in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, enums

I'm trying to make a list with the raw values of the cases from an enumeration with the new **SwiftUI** framework. However, I'm having a trouble with conforming the 'Data' to Identifiable protocol and I really cannot find information how to do it. It tells me "Initializer 'init(_:rowContent:)' requires that 'Data' conform to 'Identifiable'" The stub provides me with an ObjectIdentifier variable in the last extension, but don't know what should I return. Could you tell me how do it? How do I conform Data to Identifiable, so I can make a list with the raw values?

```
enum Data: String {
    case firstCase = "First string"
    case secondCase = "Second string"
    case thirdCase = "Third string"
}

extension Data: CaseIterable {
    static let randomSet = [Data.firstCase, Data.secondCase]
}

extension Data: Identifiable {
    var id: ObjectIdentifier {
        return //what?
    }

}

//-------------------------ContentView------------------------
import SwiftUI

struct Lala: View {
    var name: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(name)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        return List(Data.allCases) { i in
            Lala(name: i.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *maybe* this will help : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011170/how-to-make-an-enum-conform-to-a-protocol-in-swift

Comment: `id` can be a string or basically anything `equatable`, so it depends what you want to achive. You could return the enum's raw string value if, for example, you want all `firstCase` instances to be identified as the same. To differentiate different instances of the same case you could use associated values to store some unique identifier & return that in the `id` computed property (an enum can't have stored properties, which is why we need to use an associated value)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

<sub>⚠️ Try not to use already used names like `Data` for your internal module. I will use `MyEnum` instead in this answer</sub>

---

When something conforms to `Identifiable`, it must return something that can be identified by that. So you should return something unique to that case. For `String` base `enum`, `rawValue` is the best option you have:

```
extension MyEnum: Identifiable {
    var id: RawValue { rawValue }
}
```

Also, `enum`s can usually be identified by their selves:

```
extension MyEnum: Identifiable {
    var id: Self { self }
}
```

**⚠️ Note 1**: If you return something that is unstable, like **UUID()** or an **index**, this means you get a new object each time you get the object and this will kill reusability and can cause epic memory and layout process usage beside view management issues like transition management and etc.

Take a look at this weird animation for adding a new pet:
[image: UUID Example]

**Note 2**: From Swift 5.1, single-line closures don't need the `return` keyword.

**Note 3**: Try not to use globally known names like `Data` for your own types. At least use namespace for that like `MyCustomNameSpace.Data`

---

## Inline mode

You can make any collection iterable *inline* by one of it's element's keypath:

For example to `self`:

```
List(MyEnum.allCases, id:\.self)
```

or to any other compatible keypath:

```
List(MyEnum.allCases, id:\.rawValue)
```

---

## ✅ The checklist of the identifier: (from WWDC21)

- **Exercise caution with random identifiers.**
- **Use stable identifiers.**
- **Ensure the uniqueness, one identifier per item.**

Comment: Could you elaborate on why a UUID will degrade performance?

Comment: It will not! returning **A NEW** UUID each time will force the engine to build a brand new component instead of reusing the old one.

Comment: Got it, thanks for clarifying. Is there any documentation on how the id that's passed in is used by SwiftUI to determine if a view needs to be invalidated/created/recreated?

Comment: The id must be unique **per** unique data. You just pass the data and let the render engine decide whether it needs an invalidated/created/recreated object. I think you should search around "List" and "identifier" and their documentations.

Comment: @PeterKaminski I know this didn't exist at the time you wrote this comment, but for anyone in the future as well - check out the demystifying SwiftUI WWDC21 session [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/).

Comment: Isn't the issue in your UUID example that you made the id property a computed one instead of a stored? 
A computed property will create a new UUID every time it is accessed while a stored will not. 
How will the example look like if you change it to "var id = UUID()"?

Answer (score 6):

Another approach with associated values would be to do something like this, where all the associated values are identifiable.

```
enum DataEntryType: Identifiable {
    var id: String {
        switch self {
        case .thing1ThatIsIdentifiable(let thing1):
            return thing1.id
        case .thing2ThatIsIdentifiable(let thing2):
            return thing2.id
        }
    }
    
    case thing1ThatIsIdentifiable(AnIdentifiableObject)
    case thing2ThatIsIdentifiable(AnotherIdentifiableObject)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can try this way:

```
enum MyEnum: Identifiable {
    case valu1, valu2
    
    var id: Int {
        get {
            hashValue
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on a couple of answers above, this is an example where the enum it self is the `id` conforming the `Identifiable`.

```
enum Foo : Identifiable {
    var id: Foo {
        self
    }
    
    case one
    case two
}
```

And if you need it to make it for an enum with associated values, the trick is to also implement `Hashable`

```
enum Foo : Hashable, Identifiable {
    
    var id: Self {
        self
    }
    
    case one(foo: String)
    case two
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Copyright © 2021 Mark Moeykens. All rights reserved. | @BigMtnStudio
Combine Mastery in SwiftUI book

```
enum InvalidAgeError: String, Error , Identifiable {
    var id: String { rawValue }
    case lessThanZero = "Cannot be less than zero"
    case moreThanOneHundred = "Cannot be more than 100"
}
```